# Simplifying trig expression $\frac{1}{1-\cos \theta}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I need help with the following trig problem, I'm getting the first part, but can't seem to complete it.

$$\frac{\cos \theta}{1-\cos^2 \theta}- \frac{1}{1-\cos \theta}$$

The first part is going to equal $\csc^2 \theta \cos \theta$ minus the second part.

Please help me solve the second part or the complete problem in general

Comment: Note that $1-\cos^2(\theta) = (1-\cos(\theta))(1+\cos(\theta))$

Comment: A common goal when simplifying is to try and get things to become as similar as possible, because then it is easier to see what cancels out.

Comment: When adding (or subtracting) two fractions, try to get a common denominator first.

Answer (score 3):

Multiply the second fraction by $\frac{1+\cos \theta}{1 + \cos \theta}$ to get $$\frac{\cos \theta}{1 - \cos^2 \theta} - \frac{1 + \cos \theta}{(1 - \cos \theta)(1 + \cos \theta)} = \frac{-1}{1 - \cos^2 \theta} = -\csc^2 \theta$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac { \cos  \theta  }{ 1-\cos ^{ 2 } \theta  } -\frac { 1 }{ 1-\cos  \theta  } =\frac { \cos  \theta -1-\cos  \theta  }{ \left( 1-\cos  \theta  \right) \left( 1+\cos  \theta  \right)  } =-\frac { 1 }{ 1-\cos ^{ 2 } \theta  } =-\frac { 1 }{ \sin ^{ 2 }{ \theta  }  } =-\csc ^{ 2 }{ \theta  } $$